# mysql query browser: is it possible to undo change?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have updated a table in a database using mysql query browser. is it possible to roll back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Fraid not.  If you don't have a backup and the update was not run inside an as yet uncommitted transaction then there isn't much you can do.  Using the [safe-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) option can help prevent some kinds of mistakes, generally those where the where clause has been forgotten however again is no help retrospectively.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the **rollback** button on the Mysql Query Browser toobar. If it doesn't work, the change has already been committed and cannot be undone anymore. Try retrieving things from a backup instead.

Comment: rollback button does not exist in mysql query browser